# Script para convertir JSON en XML Python

Tags: python, json, xml

tengo una pregunta.

Necesito hacer un pequeño script que me convierta json a xml, esto normalmente seria bastante sencillo pero yo estoy haciendo el script para un ERP que tiene integrado una parte de scripts que se hacen en python, pero al estar integrado no te deja usar todas las funciones como por ejemplo "open with", entonces hay que meter el codigo json en una variable y que lo lea desde ahi.

Os dejo mi codigo, el json y el fallo que me da el programa.

```
import json as j
import xml.etree.ElementTree as e
from xml.etree import ElementTree
x = i_json
d = j.loads(x)
def setLNCD():

    r = e.Element("xmltest1")
    record = e.SubElement(r,"records")
    for z in d["records"]:
        e.SubElement(record,"MDLNCD").text = z["Language"]
        a = e.ElementTree(r)
        o_xml = a



{
  "transaction" : "LstItmLanguages",
  "records" : [ {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "DE",
    "MDITDS" : "Stift"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "ES",
    "MDITDS" : "BULON"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "FR",
    "MDITDS" : "AXE"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "GB",
    "MDITDS" : "PIN4111142"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "IT",
    "MDITDS" : "ITLngTst"
  }, {
   "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "NL",
    "MDITDS" : "Pentest"
  } ]
} ]
```

Y aquí el error:

```
"scripting.Traceback (most recent call last): File "script", line 5, in <module> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 28 column 3 (char 563)"
```

El xml tendria que tener este formato al final:

```
Output:
<languages>
               <language>DE</language>
               <Description>Stift</Description>
</languages>
<languages>
               <language>ES</language>
               <Description>BULON</Description>
</languages>
```

Comment: El error es un error de decodificación en el json. ¿Qué contiene la variable `x`?

Comment: La variable x es una variable de entrada que se define en el programa , seria donde iria el JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El json no está bien formado. Hay un corchete de más al final (lo marqué con asteriscos).

```
   "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "NL",
    "MDITDS" : "Pentest"
  } ]
} **]**
```

La solución sería quitar ese corchete.

*Nota* No se con exactitud de que modo debe de estar formado el json. Pero viendo como lo procesa tu código, pareciera que este es el formato correcto.

*Nota 2* Incluso solucionando esto, ocurrirá un error en esta linea `e.SubElement(record,"MDLNCD").text = z["Language"]`, ya que no hay ningún object en el array records que tenga la clave "Language".

*Recomendación* Para hacer de tu código más entendible, te diría que los nombres de variables deberían reflejar el proposito que estas tienen, en lugar de ser una sola letra. Ejemplo `suma = 1 + 2`.

Comment: Tienes razon, ahora el script se ejecuta perfectamente, pero no imprime nada.

Comment: No le indicas en ninguna parte que imprima, por eso no lo hace.

Comment: Perdon por preguntar otra vez pero es el primer script que hago en python, puse esta linea al final pero sigue sin mostrarme nada,  que tendria que poner?import json as j
import xml.etree.ElementTree as e
from xml.etree import ElementTree
x = i_json
d = j.loads(x)
def setLNCD():

    r = e.Element("xmltest1")
    record = e.SubElement(r,"records")
    for z in d["records"]:
        e.SubElement(record,"MDLNCD").text = z["MDLNCD"]
        e.SubElement(record,"MDITDS").text = z["MDITDS"]
        a = e.ElementTree(r)
        o_xml = a
        a.write(o_xml)

Comment: No se, ya que no se nada xml y por lo tanto de ese modulo que usas, pero la función que envía texto a la pantalla es [print](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#print). Eso puede darte un empujoncito inicial muy pequeño para que puedas avanzar. Por cierto, para ser tu primera vez en Python está bueno tu código c: Lo unico que cambiaría es eso de usar una sola letra como variable.